# Declare receiver in mainactivity

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a `webView` declared like this (MainActivity.java)

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static WebView webView;
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);        
    webView.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
}
```

A receiver handles connection changes (BroadcastReceiver.java)

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionBroadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            MainActivity.webView.reload();
        } else {
            MainActivity.webView.reload();
        }    
    }
}
```

The manifest (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_full"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".ConnectionBroadReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Because "webView" is a "public static WebView webView;" I can't invoke virtual method from another class..

> onBroadReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.reload()' on a null object
>   reference

How can I do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You don't have to make the `WebView` static. You can broadcast another message to your activity and handle the connection changes.  http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/android-development/broadcast-receiver-from-activity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of registering `receiver` in `manifest` , register it in `Activity` and pass `interface` to interact on network state change

**NetworkCallback.java**

```
interface NetworkCallback{
  void onStateChange();
}
```

**ConnectionBroadReceiver.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionBroadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   private NetworkCallback callback;

    public ConnectionBroadReceiver(NetworkCallback callback){
          this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            callback.onStateChange();
        } else {
             callback.onStateChange();
        }    
    }
}
```

Now in your Ativity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private WebView webView;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // you code to set content view
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);        
    webView.postUrl(url, postData.getBytes());
    registerReceiver(new ConnectionBroadReceiver(new NetworkCallback(){
          @Override
          public void onStateChange(){
               webview.reload();
          }
     }),new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I have some syntax errors, could you check please ? Don't really see where I must add "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"
There is a ")" before a "}" in the answer so I don't see how to register the receiver....

Comment: Thank you ^^ but "Local variable webView is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final"

Comment: glad i could help :)